# Constructing ColorData with blue, white and red color

Tags: plotting, function-construction, color

I'm trying to compare different calculation following different approaches and software programs. I basically plot a `DensityPlot` with the following legend color bars:

[image: color bars]

The bar on the left was generated by Python, while the bar on the right was generated by Mathematica via `ColorData[{"RedBlueTones", "Reverse"}]`. Although they are very similarly, the one in Mathematica doesn't have the 'white' color transition between blue and red. I'm wondering whether it would be possible to have this 'white' color transitions in Mathematica too. Can I create my own `ColorData` style using the colors from Python Colorbar?

Thanks!

Comment: "Can I create my own `ColorData` style using the colors from Python Colorbar?" - this is possible, but you hadn't specified which colormap (from matplotlib?) you're using.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about

```
French = Blend[{{0, Blue}, {1/2 - 0.1, White},
     {1/2 + 0.1, White}, {1, Red}}, #1] &;
```

Then

```
  French /@ (Range[15]/15.)
```

[image]

```
ContourPlot[x, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, ColorFunction -> French]
```

[image]

Any variation is possible: e.g.

```
French2 = Blend[{{0, Darker[Blue, 0.7]}, {0.15, Blue}, {1/2 - 0.05, 
      White},
     {1/2 + 0.05, White}, {0.9, Red}, {1, Darker[Red, 0.5]}}, #1] &;
```

[image]

Or alternatively,

```
col0 = Join[
   ColorData["SiennaTones"] /@ (Range[0, 15]/15), 
   {White},
   ColorData[{"DeepSeaColors", "Reverse"}] /@ (Range[0, 15]/15)];
nn = Length[col0] - 1;

col[x_] = Blend[Transpose[{Range[0, nn]/nn, col0}], x];

col /@ (Range[0,12]/12.)
```

[image]

Then

```
ContourPlot[x y, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, ColorFunction -> col,  Contours -> 36, 
ContourStyle -> None, PlotRange -> Full]
```

[image]

---

**Update**

If you want something which looks more closely to  [brewer-23](https://journals.ametsoc.org/view/journals/bams/96/2/bams-d-13-00155.1.xml)

```
col0=List[List[0,RGBColor[List[Rational[103,255],0,Rational[31,255]]]],List[Rational[1,23],RGBColor[List[Rational[8,15],Rational[3,85],Rational[7,51]]]],List[Rational[2,23],RGBColor[List[Rational[167,255],Rational[19,255],Rational[8,51]]]],List[Rational[3,23],RGBColor[List[Rational[63,85],Rational[44,255],Rational[52,255]]]],List[Rational[4,23],RGBColor[List[Rational[41,51],Rational[74,255],Rational[67,255]]]],List[Rational[5,23],RGBColor[List[Rational[44,51],Rational[104,255],Rational[28,85]]]],List[Rational[6,23],RGBColor[List[Rational[232,255],Rational[133,255],Rational[7,17]]]],List[Rational[7,23],RGBColor[List[Rational[244,255],Rational[163,255],Rational[128,255]]]],List[Rational[8,23],RGBColor[List[Rational[50,51],Rational[62,85],Rational[52,85]]]],List[Rational[9,23],RGBColor[List[Rational[254,255],Rational[211,255],Rational[188,255]]]],List[Rational[10,23],RGBColor[List[Rational[254,255],Rational[227,255],Rational[212,255]]]],List[Rational[11,23],RGBColor[List[Rational[251,255],Rational[16,17],Rational[232,255]]]],List[Rational[12,23],RGBColor[List[Rational[82,85],Rational[247,255],Rational[83,85]]]],List[Rational[13,23],RGBColor[List[Rational[77,85],Rational[241,255],Rational[49,51]]]],List[Rational[14,23],RGBColor[List[Rational[43,51],Rational[233,255],Rational[242,255]]]],List[Rational[15,23],RGBColor[List[Rational[193,255],Rational[223,255],Rational[14,15]]]],List[Rational[16,23],RGBColor[List[Rational[167,255],Rational[208,255],Rational[229,255]]]],List[Rational[17,23],RGBColor[List[Rational[46,85],Rational[193,255],Rational[13,15]]]],List[Rational[18,23],RGBColor[List[Rational[104,255],Rational[172,255],Rational[209,255]]]],List[Rational[19,23],RGBColor[List[Rational[5,17],Rational[3,5],Rational[199,255]]]],List[Rational[20,23],RGBColor[List[Rational[56,255],Rational[134,255],Rational[63,85]]]],List[Rational[21,23],RGBColor[List[Rational[14,85],Rational[23,51],Rational[12,17]]]],List[Rational[22,23],RGBColor[List[Rational[29,255],Rational[97,255],Rational[11,17]]]],List[1,RGBColor[List[Rational[6,85],Rational[74,255],Rational[134,255]]]]];
```

So that

```
col0//Transpose
```

[image]

Then

```
col[x_] = Blend[col0, x]
```

Would work like this:

```
ContourPlot[Sin[ 10 x y] , {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, ColorFunction -> col]
```

[image]

Or

```
ContourPlot[x y , {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, ColorFunction -> col, 
 Contours -> 26, ContourStyle -> None, PlotRange -> Full]
```

[image]

Comment: Here's a more compact way to define your `col`: `With[{col0 = RGBColor /@ {"#67001f", "#880923", "#a71328", "#bd2c34", "#cd4a43", "#dc6854", "#e88569", "#f4a380", "#faba9c", "#fed3bc", "#fee3d4", "#fbf0e8", "#f6f7f9", "#e7f1f5", "#d7e9f2", "#c1dfee", "#a7d0e5", "#8ac1dd", "#68acd1", "#4b99c7", "#3886bd", "#2a73b4", "#1d61a5", "#124a86"}}, col[x_] := Blend[col0, x]]`

Comment: @J.M. Thank you! You may recall that you taught me this stuff!

Answer (score 4):

A cheap way to get what you want is to use `Lighter[]` along with `"RedBlueTones"` and an appropriate bell-shaped curve:

```
LinearGradientImage[Function[x, Lighter[ColorData["RedBlueTones", x],
                                        Sech[5 (x - 1/2)]]], {300, 30}]
```

[image: modified gradient]

```
ContourPlot[x y, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
            ColorFunction -> (Lighter[ColorData["RedBlueTones", #], 
                                      Sech[7.2 (# - 0.5)]] &),
            Contours -> 26, ContourStyle -> None, PlotRange -> Full]
```

[image: contour plot with modified gradient]