# TemperatureMap Background of Dataset Cells based on their Value

Tags: color, dataset, style, background

I have a dataset with normal numbers (either integers or real) and I would like to visualize the dataset in a table where, for every row a colormap shows the ranking of the numbers from Min (blue) to Max (red) but I cannot find an option to do that.

For example like this:

```
    myDataset = Dataset[{<|"a" -> 5, "b" -> 7, "c" -> 2|>,
   <|"a" -> 3.3, "b" -> 5.1, "c" -> 9.7|>}]
```

I came across something that includes this code here from [this example](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2240112), but I don't find a way to apply it to my datset

```
primarydiffs=primarywardvotes[All,<|"TJ-CS"->#["TISHAURA JONES"]-#["CARA SPENCER"],"TJ-LR"->#["TISHAURA JONES"]-#["LEWIS REED"],\[IndentingNewLine]"CS-LR"->#["CARA SPENCER"]-#["LEWIS REED"]\[IndentingNewLine]|>&] 
wdmax=primarydiffs[Max];wdmin=primarydiffs[Min]; 
addBG=Dataset[#,Background->{(ColorData["TemperatureMap"][(#1-wdmin)/(wdmax-wdmin)]&)}]&;
```

The datasets that I want to apply it to are either ALL integers or ALL real numbers, not mixed as my example up.

Appreciate your help!

**Edit:**

And how would I do that if I would not the last two columns do be included in that? So only columns 2-8 should be "temperaturemapped", i.e. [All, 2;;8].
And again, the temperaturemap only per row, not vertically.

**Edit2:**
Here is a bigger example dataset, I already included a proposed code from @Syed.
So the first column should be ignored (is not part of the calculation, just a district number, and the last 2 also should not be included. Or get their own temperaturemap, but they would need it vertically in the column, i.e. across districts. Is that possible?
Otherwise I am fine if it is per district (=row) for Party 1 to Party 7.

```
myDataset2 = 
 Dataset[{<|"District No." -> 1, 
    "Party 1" -> RandomInteger[10000; 100000], 
    "Party 2" -> RandomInteger[10000; 100000], 
    "Party 3" ->  RandomInteger[10000; 100000], 
    "Party 4" -> RandomInteger[10000; 100000], 
    "Party 5" -> RandomInteger[10000; 100000], 
    "Party 6" -> RandomInteger[10000; 100000],  
    "Party 7" -> RandomInteger[10000; 100000], 
    "Invalid" -> RandomInteger[10000; 100000], 
    "Absent" -> RandomInteger[10000; 100000]|>,
   <|"District No." -> 2, "Party 1" -> RandomInteger[10000; 100000], 
    "Party 2" -> RandomInteger[10000; 100000], 
    "Party 3" ->  RandomInteger[10000; 100000], 
    "Party 4" -> RandomInteger[10000; 100000], 
    "Party 5" -> RandomInteger[10000; 100000], 
    "Party 6" -> RandomInteger[10000; 100000],  
    "Party 7" -> RandomInteger[10000; 100000], 
    "Invalid" -> RandomInteger[10000; 100000], 
    "Absent" -> RandomInteger[10000; 100000]|>,
   <|"District No." -> 3, "Party 1" -> RandomInteger[10000; 100000], 
    "Party 2" -> RandomInteger[10000; 100000], 
    "Party 3" ->  RandomInteger[10000; 100000], 
    "Party 4" -> RandomInteger[10000; 100000], 
    "Party 5" -> RandomInteger[10000; 100000], 
    "Party 6" -> RandomInteger[10000; 100000],  
    "Party 7" -> RandomInteger[10000; 100000], 
    "Invalid" -> RandomInteger[10000; 100000], 
    "Absent" -> RandomInteger[10000; 100000]|>,
   <|"District No." -> 4, "Party 1" -> RandomInteger[10000; 100000], 
    "Party 2" -> RandomInteger[10000; 100000], 
    "Party 3" ->  RandomInteger[10000; 100000], 
    "Party 4" -> RandomInteger[10000; 100000], 
    "Party 5" -> RandomInteger[10000; 100000], 
    "Party 6" -> RandomInteger[10000; 100000],  
    "Party 7" -> RandomInteger[10000; 100000], 
    "Invalid" -> RandomInteger[10000; 100000], 
    "Absent" -> RandomInteger[10000; 100000]|>,
   <|"District No." -> 5, "Party 1" -> RandomInteger[10000; 100000], 
    "Party 2" -> RandomInteger[10000; 100000], 
    "Party 3" ->  RandomInteger[10000; 100000], 
    "Party 4" -> RandomInteger[10000; 100000], 
    "Party 5" -> RandomInteger[10000; 100000], 
    "Party 6" -> RandomInteger[10000; 100000],  
    "Party 7" -> RandomInteger[10000; 100000], 
    "Invalid" -> RandomInteger[10000; 100000], 
    "Absent" -> RandomInteger[10000; 100000]|>
   }, Background -> {(ColorData["LightTemperatureMap"][
       Rescale[#, MinMax[myDataset2]]] &)}]
```

Comment: Could you please include a more representative dataset that is more similar in size and contents to the data you are actually dealing with?

Comment: @MarcoB I have added a big example dataset that is like the ones I have

Comment: What's the purpose of all the `10000;`?

Answer (score 4):

Here's how I would do it:

```
Dataset[
 Table[
  <|
   "District No." -> i,
   # -> RandomInteger[100000] & /@ {"Party 1", "Party 2", "Party 3", 
     "Party 4", "Party 5", "Party 6", "Party 7", "Invalid", "Absent"}
   |>, {i, 10}
  ],
 Background -> {
   s : "Invalid" | "Absent" -> (
     ColorData["Rainbow"]@Rescale[#, MinMax@#3[[All, #2[[2]]]]] &
     ),
   p_String /; StringStartsQ[p, "Party"] -> (
     ColorData["TemperatureMap"]@
       Rescale[#, MinMax@#3[[#2[[1]], 2 ;; -3]]] &
     )
   }]
```

[image]

This uses three ingredients:

- The colors are computed using `ColorData[map][Rescale[value,MinMax@values]]`. This colors the value `value` using the colormap `map`, assuming the values over the range covered by `values`.
- The positions where to apply the coloring can be specified using patterns: We use this to apply some rules to elements in `"Invalid"` and `"Absent"`, and one for anything starting with `"Party"`.
- The style specifications can be functions with three arguments, being called as `func[value,position,dataset]`. We get the relevant subset of values for the color function using the position information in the second argument, and extract the corresponding range from the last argument

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of mapping each column separately (only Background-> shown). I made Party 3 going from 1000 to 10000, and Party 4 going from 100000 to 1000000. Other columns are 10000 to 100000.

```
Background -> ({
   {All, 
     "Party 1"} -> {(ColorData["LightTemperatureMap"][
        Rescale[#, MinMax[myDataset2[All, {{"Party 1"}}]]]] &)},
   {All, 
     "Party 2"} -> {(ColorData["LightTemperatureMap"][
        Rescale[#, MinMax[myDataset2[All, {{"Party 2"}}]]]] &)},
   {All, 
     "Party 3"} -> {(ColorData["LightTemperatureMap"][
        Rescale[#, MinMax[myDataset2[All, {{"Party 3"}}]]]] &)},
   {All, 
     "Party 4"} -> {(ColorData["LightTemperatureMap"][
        Rescale[#, MinMax[myDataset2[All, {{"Party 4"}}]]]] &)},
   {All, 
     "Party 5"} -> {(ColorData["LightTemperatureMap"][
        Rescale[#, MinMax[myDataset2[All, {{"Party 5"}}]]]] &)},
   {All, 
     "Party 6"} -> {(ColorData["LightTemperatureMap"][
        Rescale[#, MinMax[myDataset2[All, {{"Party 6"}}]]]] &)},
   {All, 
     "Party 7"} -> {(ColorData["LightTemperatureMap"][
        Rescale[#, MinMax[myDataset2[All, {{"Party 7"}}]]]] &)}
   })
```

[image]

Here is an example where the mapping is applied to each row separately. In this case, I entered each individual cell. I also defined variable `partyList` to save some typing.

```
partyList={"Party 1", "Party 2", "Party 3", "Party 4", "Party 5", "Party 6","Party 7"};
```

Here is the Background:

```
Background -> ({
   {1, "Party 1"} -> {(ColorData["LightTemperatureMap"][
        Rescale[#, MinMax[myDataset2[[1, partyList]]]]] &)},
   {1, "Party 2"} -> {(ColorData["LightTemperatureMap"][
        Rescale[#, MinMax[myDataset2[[1, partyList]]]]] &)},
   {1, "Party 3"} -> {(ColorData["LightTemperatureMap"][
        Rescale[#, MinMax[myDataset2[[1, partyList]]]]] &)},
   {1, "Party 4"} -> {(ColorData["LightTemperatureMap"][
        Rescale[#, MinMax[myDataset2[[1, partyList]]]]] &)},
   {1, "Party 5"} -> {(ColorData["LightTemperatureMap"][
        Rescale[#, MinMax[myDataset2[[1, partyList]]]]] &)},
   {1, "Party 6"} -> {(ColorData["LightTemperatureMap"][
        Rescale[#, MinMax[myDataset2[[1, partyList]]]]] &)},
   {1, "Party 7"} -> {(ColorData["LightTemperatureMap"][
        Rescale[#, MinMax[myDataset2[[1, partyList]]]]] &)},
   
   {2, "Party 1"} -> {(ColorData["LightTemperatureMap"][
        Rescale[#, MinMax[myDataset2[[2, partyList]]]]] &)},
   {2, "Party 2"} -> {(ColorData["LightTemperatureMap"][
        Rescale[#, MinMax[myDataset2[[2, partyList]]]]] &)},
   {2, "Party 3"} -> {(ColorData["LightTemperatureMap"][
        Rescale[#, MinMax[myDataset2[[2, partyList]]]]] &)},
   {2, "Party 4"} -> {(ColorData["LightTemperatureMap"][
        Rescale[#, MinMax[myDataset2[[2, partyList]]]]] &)},
   {2, "Party 5"} -> {(ColorData["LightTemperatureMap"][
        Rescale[#, MinMax[myDataset2[[2, partyList]]]]] &)},
   {2, "Party 6"} -> {(ColorData["LightTemperatureMap"][
        Rescale[#, MinMax[myDataset2[[2, partyList]]]]] &)},
   {2, "Party 7"} -> {(ColorData["LightTemperatureMap"][
        Rescale[#, MinMax[myDataset2[[2, partyList]]]]] &)},
   
   {3, "Party 1"} -> {(ColorData["LightTemperatureMap"][
        Rescale[#, MinMax[myDataset2[[3, partyList]]]]] &)},
   {3, "Party 2"} -> {(ColorData["LightTemperatureMap"][
        Rescale[#, MinMax[myDataset2[[3, partyList]]]]] &)},
   {3, "Party 3"} -> {(ColorData["LightTemperatureMap"][
        Rescale[#, MinMax[myDataset2[[3, partyList]]]]] &)},
   {3, "Party 4"} -> {(ColorData["LightTemperatureMap"][
        Rescale[#, MinMax[myDataset2[[3, partyList]]]]] &)},
   {3, "Party 5"} -> {(ColorData["LightTemperatureMap"][
        Rescale[#, MinMax[myDataset2[[3, partyList]]]]] &)},
   {3, "Party 6"} -> {(ColorData["LightTemperatureMap"][
        Rescale[#, MinMax[myDataset2[[3, partyList]]]]] &)},
   {3, "Party 7"} -> {(ColorData["LightTemperatureMap"][
        Rescale[#, MinMax[myDataset2[[3, partyList]]]]] &)},
   
   {4, "Party 1"} -> {(ColorData["LightTemperatureMap"][
        Rescale[#, MinMax[myDataset2[[4, partyList]]]]] &)},
   {4, "Party 2"} -> {(ColorData["LightTemperatureMap"][
        Rescale[#, MinMax[myDataset2[[4, partyList]]]]] &)},
   {4, "Party 3"} -> {(ColorData["LightTemperatureMap"][
        Rescale[#, MinMax[myDataset2[[4, partyList]]]]] &)},
   {4, "Party 4"} -> {(ColorData["LightTemperatureMap"][
        Rescale[#, MinMax[myDataset2[[4, partyList]]]]] &)},
   {4, "Party 5"} -> {(ColorData["LightTemperatureMap"][
        Rescale[#, MinMax[myDataset2[[4, partyList]]]]] &)},
   {4, "Party 6"} -> {(ColorData["LightTemperatureMap"][
        Rescale[#, MinMax[myDataset2[[4, partyList]]]]] &)},
   {4, "Party 7"} -> {(ColorData["LightTemperatureMap"][
        Rescale[#, MinMax[myDataset2[[4, partyList]]]]] &)},
   
   {5, "Party 1"} -> {(ColorData["LightTemperatureMap"][
        Rescale[#, MinMax[myDataset2[[5, partyList]]]]] &)},
   {5, "Party 2"} -> {(ColorData["LightTemperatureMap"][
        Rescale[#, MinMax[myDataset2[[5, partyList]]]]] &)},
   {5, "Party 3"} -> {(ColorData["LightTemperatureMap"][
        Rescale[#, MinMax[myDataset2[[5, partyList]]]]] &)},
   {5, "Party 4"} -> {(ColorData["LightTemperatureMap"][
        Rescale[#, MinMax[myDataset2[[5, partyList]]]]] &)},
   {5, "Party 5"} -> {(ColorData["LightTemperatureMap"][
        Rescale[#, MinMax[myDataset2[[5, partyList]]]]] &)},
   {5, "Party 6"} -> {(ColorData["LightTemperatureMap"][
        Rescale[#, MinMax[myDataset2[[5, partyList]]]]] &)},
   {5, "Party 7"} -> {(ColorData["LightTemperatureMap"][
        Rescale[#, MinMax[myDataset2[[5, partyList]]]]] &)}
   
   })
```

[image]

This can be simplified as there are redundancies.

Comment: The procedure seems good, but, for example for District 1, why does it use the same blue tone for party 2, 3, 4, 6 and 7? The point would be to assign different colors to each party (horizontally) so I can see which party scored most and least in each district. Another step would be to do it vertically, to see in which district did a party score most. Of course this would not work with absolute number of votes and would need percentages. But regardless, how would I have to adjust the code?

Comment: What I posted up there is the color map of each column separately. So in Party 3, 8985 is red since it is the highest in the column, but in Party 2, a similar value (7356) is blue.

Comment: Ah I had understood "across columns" as horizontally, showing the Min-Max of the parties per district. But that is what I need, how do I adjust it to color horizontally and show the best/worst parties of each district?

Comment: Good point! I will change the text.

Comment: And please how I visualize the colormap horizontally. Knowing both options is good, so thank you for the vertical one. Just the horizontal one is important and I don't really understand in Mathematica how I adress specific rows and colums. I checked out the help a million times, but i can't make sense of it and usually just keep trying millions of possibilities until it eventually fits (or I decide that I don't want it after all)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my first thought to handle this. First, define a color set (see [This thread](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/240489/constructing-colordata-with-blue-white-and-red-color)).

```
colorSet = Blend[{{0, Blue}, {1/2 - 0.1, White}, {1/2 + 0.1, White},{1,Red}}, #1] &
```

Then map it over a range:

```
colorSet /@ (Range[15]/15.)
```

Then define the data set and use `Background` with your color set.

```
myDataset = 
 Dataset[{<|"a" -> 5, "b" -> 7, "c" -> 2|>, <|"a" -> 3.3, "b" -> 5.1, 
    "c" -> 9.7|>}, Background -> (colorSet[#/Max[myDataset]] &)]
```

[image: Result]